# PHP_HTML layout the result of a query

Tags: php, button, layout, product

I want to create a product page, I would like the products of my page to be represented this way: http://www.mvphiphop.com/Brand-Shoes-c92/ or something similar but something really simple with no css if possible (image of product, name, price, order). I mean just in terms on the products, nothing about the page numbering and the brand.

How can I do that? is it hard? I can return all the products of my database with no problem but I have no idea how to lay it out this way. Could you help me. I have been searching for the past 2 weeks some tutorial but in vain.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean, with no css? why? what have you got? how does your code look at the moment?

Comment: Or a little css, nothing too hard. Well my code returns me the name of the product the image and price but on the same line. `<?php echo ($name.','. $price .','. $img) ?>`.

Comment: if you put a `<br/>` in there, you have them on seperate lines. So bascally you ask how to copy that website? Rightmouse, view source, ctrl-a, ctr-c, open editor, ctrl-v...

Comment: I don't necessarily want to copy but do something similar, which will allow me to put the picture on top, then name then price. And for the product to be inline and not underneath

Comment: And they are using css on the website. @Nanne

Answer (score 0):

No CSS... so... `<TABLE>`'s >

Comment: with css is there some template i can use? or with a table  is hard and how can i put the results next to each other so inline. Thanks

Comment: maybe use some part of the example you gave us

Comment: that is the way i am printing my values `<?php echo ($name.','. $price .','. $img) ?>` which I know won't lay it out as i want.

Comment: `<table>
  <tr class="smth">
 <td><?= $row['img']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="smthElse">
 <td><?= $row['name']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="else">
 <td><?= $row['price']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>` ... For better styling, make the block elements - inline or smth else, check out in the web how to manipulate elements to float or something via CSS by their class or id

Comment: Thanks, will try. Is css easy to learn in short amount of time? @ RoyalBg